# Ajax Request wont work unless I use alert()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've been trying for hours to get this to work, but it's just not budging; I have the following code:

```
var text = "";
function getText(c1, c2)
{
    url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&titles=" + c1 + "-" + c2 + "_relations&prop=revisions&rvprop=content"
    $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         dataType: "jsonp",
         async: false,
         url: url,
         success: function (data) {
                var obj = (data.query.pages );
                var keys = [];
                for(var k in obj) keys.push(k);
                if (keys[0] == -1) { 
                    //Link doesnt exist
                    text = "-1";            
                    return text;
                }
                //Link Exists
                else {
                        link = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + c1 + "-" + c2 + "_relations"
                        text = c1 + "-" + c2 + " Relations"                     
                        return text;
                }
            }

    });
    return text;
}   

var a = (getText(country1, country2))
alert(text);
alert(a);
```

I'm making an ajax request; a simple inquiry to see if wiki has a page between any 2 given countrie.
If I use alert inside, it works fine, and it returns the correct data inside the text variable. However, when the getText function is called outside, the text variable is always empty. I've tried everything I can think of, including getting the app to sleep for some time, but even that didn't work. I know the async doesn't work from ajax 1.8 onwards, but is there anyway around this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `1)` Do not use `async: false`... ever `2)` Any problems, see `1)`. please learn how to use async ajax calls (or Ajax promises) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the asynchronous behavior of ajax. You can't return values from ajax like this way. Because the function will not wait for the success event to happen.

When you put an alert inside that function, success event may occur before the user clicks on alert. That is why it returning value. Otherwise it will not return the value.

Its not a good practice to use `async : false` in ajax calls. It will freeze the browser.

Good practice is to call a method from the ajax success with the returned data, then do operations with that data inside the function.

Comment: It's an `async: false` call... :(

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie then my answer is wrong. I didnt notice that 'async : false'

Comment: @AnoopJoshi he's using JSONP - the `async: false` is being ignored.

Comment: The situation was far worse than originally thought :)

Comment: @Alnitak Thats a new info to me. Thanks for it..

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie any way, we only can suggest, its the choice of  OP to follow the good approach.

Comment: So the only way to do this is to do everything inside the call?

Comment: call a method from ajax success with returned data.

Comment: Does that mean many functions will be nested? (Since I make many requests to many sites)

Comment: no. its asynchronous. So your functions will not wait for the ajax success. So it wont be nested.